# Is it possible to create an app (preferably web-based) for a google form?

Tags: forms, google-forms

I've created a Google Form to tabulate commercial/chartered flight data for my company. However, I would like to convert the form such that it can be accessed through an employee's mobile directly(straight from their home screen). Is this possible and what would be the best route to take?